# Jsonpath return null for nested JSON objects in Spring Boot Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsonpath

In a Spring Boot test I need to compare/matching the result from a call to a rest controller with a Java entity previously created that have nested objects.

This is the Java entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Referente")
public class Referente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idReferente", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer idReferente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idCliente")
    private Cliente cliente;

    @Column(name = "cognomeReferente")
    private String cognomeReferente;

...
```

The nested object Cliente have another nested object called Agente:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idCliente", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer idCliente;

    @Column(name = "nominativo")
    private String nominativo;

    @Column(name = "dataProssimoContatto")
    private LocalDateTime dataProssimoContatto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAgentePrimoContatto")
    private Agente agentePrimoContatto;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="Agente")
public class Agente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idAgente", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer idAgente;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome")
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "telefono")
    private String telefono;
```

This is the test method:

```
@Test
public void getAllReferente_Test() throws Exception {

 initializeData();

 mvc.perform(get("/referente").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].idReferente").value(referente1.getIdReferente()))
// Here the error 
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].cliente").value(referente1.getCliente()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].cognomeReferente").value(referente1.getCognomeReferente()));
```

When I run the test method I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$[0].cliente" 

expected:<Cliente [idCliente=1, nominativo=NOMINATIVOCLIENTE1, dataProssimoContatto=2019-10-16T16:19:59.111111111, agentePrimoContatto=Agente [idAgente=1, nome=NOME1, cognome=COGNOME1, telefono=11111, mail=MAIL1, isRemovibile=null], dataPrimoContatto=2019-07-20, agenteInEssere=Agente [idAgente=1, nome=NOME1, cognome=COGNOME1, telefono=11111, mail=MAIL1, isRemovibile=null], consensoPrivacy=true, indirizzo=VIA INDIRIZZO1, cap=11111, citta=CITTA1, provincia=PR, settoreMerceologico=SettoreMerceologico [idSettoreMerceologico=1, descrizione=SETTOREMERCEOLOGIOCO], statoCliente=StatoCliente [idStatoCliente=1, descrizione=NUOVO]]> 

but was:<null>
```

But in another test case (where I don't have nested objects) everything works fine:

```
@Test
public void getAllCliente2Call() throws Exception {

  initializeData();
  mvc.perform(get("/cliente/data/" + dataProssimoContatto).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$").isNotEmpty())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].idCliente").value(cliente2.getIdCliente()))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].nominativo").value(cliente2.getNominativo())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].dataProssimoContatto",is(cliente2.getDataProssimoContatto().toString())))
// Here works fine (not have nested objects in agente)
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].agentePrimoContatto").value(cliente2.getAgentePrimoContatto()));
```

Why in the first test case JSON path "$[0].cliente" return null? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It seems you're missing the other side relationships. Have you written the both side relationships? Please add the cliente object to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I solved following this other thread:

[Matching object in JSON with jsonpath in Spring Boot Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514532/matching-object-in-json-with-jsonpath-in-spring-boot-test)

Here the code:

```
private <T> T asParsedJson(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    return JsonPath.read(json, "$");
}
```

Then

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].cliente").value(equalTo(asParsedJson(referente1.getCliente()))))
```